# Access private blockchain from another PC/Laptop?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, contract-invocation, metamask, json-rpc

I have private block chain on my PC.The private blockchain is configured and deployed using geth. I want to connect to that blockchain from another node(my laptop) to access the smart contract deployed. For that what should I have to do?

Is this possible via Metamask( connect to custom RPC)?or geth is mandatory?If I use geth, How can I download the genesis block to my laptop and become a node in the private network?

Answer (score 1):

If your PC and your laptop are on the same local network you can open rpc using this command `--rpcaddr 192.168.1.1`. You will be able to request one of your node using the json rpc api.

If you want to sync another node you will need to be on the same network, be sure that port 30303 is open on both computers and download the genesis file on your computer. Then you can start your node using the genesis file and the bootnode ip.

Comment: How to start the node using bootnode? and how can i view my private blockchain? any private blockchain explorer available?

Comment: you can use this command geth --bootnodes as shown in this link [link](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Setting-up-private-network-or-local-cluster). There is some open source blockchain explorer for ethereum, they will also work for a private network.

Comment: Before connecting the 2nd node.do I have to initialize the block chain using Genesis file? Or it will be downloaded when I connect to the private block chain?

Comment: yes you need to initialize your private chain with a genesis file and each node will need this file too. They won't download it